# How to check the process scheduling policy other than `ps` output

Tags: linux, shell, busybox

I am using an busybox version of linux and want to check the process scheduling policy. The `PS` output only displays `PID USER       VSZ STAT COMMAND` irrespective of any option given with `PS` command. Is there any other way to check the process scheduling policy?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find schedule information of a process by looking at `/proc/pocess_id/sched`.

For example:

```
awk '/policy/ {print $NF}' /proc/25/sched
```

would give you the policy number of process `25`.

For more information on policy numbers, you can look at `man sched_setscheduler`:

```
Scheduling Policies:
    ...
   For  threads scheduled under one of the normal scheduling policies
   (SCHED_OTHER, SCHED_IDLE, SCHED_BATCH), sched_priority is not used
   in scheduling decisions (it must be specified as 0).

   Processes scheduled under one of the real-time policies
   (SCHED_FIFO, SCHED_RR) have a sched_priority value in the range 1
   (low)  to  99  (high).  (As the numbers imply, real-time threads
   always have higher priority than normal threads.)  Note well:
   POSIX.1-2001 requires an implementation to support only a minimum
   32 distinct priority levels for the real-time policies, and some
   systems supply  just  this  minimum.   Portable  programs should
   use sched_get_priority_min(2) and sched_get_priority_max(2) to
   find the range of priorities supported for a particular policy.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help John. I have also tried the below code and which returns a non -ve number but unable to get any man page which shows return value (or policy #) to scheduling policy mapping.

Comment: No problem, please see my updated answer for more info on policies.

Comment: ```
#define SCHED_NORMAL            0
#define SCHED_FIFO              1
#define SCHED_RR                2
#define SCHED_BATCH             3
/* SCHED_ISO: reserved but not implemented yet */
#define SCHED_IDLE              5
#define SCHED_DEADLINE          6
```

Answer (score -1):

To know which IO scheduler your kernel has configured type:

```
cat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_DEFAULT_IOSCHED
```